# display bitmap value in image control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a bitmap and I want to display it in image control without saving it, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the bitmap to a `BitmapImage` and assign it to the property (i.e. in the example `CurrentImage`) the image control's `Source` property is bound to:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
_bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
ms.Position = 0;
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
bi.StreamSource = ms;
bi.EndInit();
CurrentImage = bi;
```

Answer (score 1):

In what way do you have the bitmap? If you a `BitmapImage`, just set the [Image.Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source.aspx) dependency property.

```
BitmapImage bitmap = ... // whatever
Image image = new Image();
image.Source = bitmap;
```

In XAML you can set it to something on disk also, or bind it.

```
<Image Source="myimage.bmp"/>
// Or ...
<Image Source="{Binding Path=PropertyInMyViewModel}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

A `BitmapImage` can take an uri as parameter:

```
BitmapImage MyImage = new BitmapImage(someuri);
```

and then you can bind your image control to it

```
<Image Source={Binding MyImage}/>
```